# Array match in while-loop

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I am developing a search tool for my project,

My desired output is to get the common value from the different tables. eg) SKR0BP100

How to get this value ??

As i am running the program in for-loop and fetching the values from while-loop, now how to use array_intersect() function? Because for array intersect function, minimum 2 arrays are needed, but i get only one array at a time, as it runs on for-loop. So what should i do ?? Please Help me!

$result = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);

But i have only one $array (ie, $sid[$i] at a time, as it runs in for-loop.

**My program**

```
for($i=0;$i<$cc;$i++)
{

$m1="select * from $u$sc where $b[$i]='$a[$i]' ";
$m2=mysql_query($m1);

echo"$m1<br><br>";

while($we=mysql_fetch_array($m2))
{
$sid[$i]=$we['SI'];

echo"$sid[$i]<br><br>";
}
    }
```

**Desired Output** =     SKR0BP100

// How to get this??

**Present output**

```
select * from Studentsc where Zone='East' 

SKR0BP100
SKR0BP12


select * from Studentsc where Area='Rural' 

SKR0BP129
SKR0BP13
SKR0BP100


select * from Studentsc where Class='12' 

SKR0BP100
SKR0BP101
```

Comment: Hum? `select * from studentsc where Zone='East' and Area='Rural' and Class='12'`

Comment: You are right! but the problem is how i can add the word "and" in the mysql syntax, as the fields are not fixed (say 3), it is user choice, i mean user will be selecting the fields (zone, area etc..) via check box, to compare. so it may be one, two or more fields

Comment: Please see the mysql syntax in my program, given above.. it runs in for-loop.. please help me

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/37555682/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/34693072/2943403

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/39232571/2943403

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/3276639/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to create query then try this

```
$where = array();
for($i=0;$i<$cc;$i++)
{
    $where[] = $b[$i]."='".$a[$i]."'";
}

$m1="select * from $u$sc where ".implode(" and ",$where); //If you are sure that atleast one value vomes
```

Comment: Sir, if i use the above syntax, (ie, $m1) "select * from $u$sc" is not displaying, i mean only the second part(where Religion='Hindu' and School='Govt' and Income='Upper-Class') is only displaying. And if the full syntax is displayed, then my program will be correct.. i wil be very great full to you!