# How to implode 'AND' in SQL query dynamically when there is single and multiple inputs

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am passing JSON input from Android and based on that I am building a Query dynamically and then running it in DB the pass the results to Android.
I am able to build the query but I am not able to add the `AND` in between the query.

```
$QueryString="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE"; 

if ( (isset($val1) && !empty($val1)) ) { 
$QueryString1 .= " `it` IN ('$val1')"; 
} 

if ((isset($val2) && !empty($val2))) { 
$QueryString1 .= " `Re` IN ('$val2')"; 
} 

if ((isset($stringgen) && !empty($stringgen))) { 
$QueryString1 .= " $stringgen"; 
} 

if ((isset($val4) && !empty($val4))) { 
$QueryString1 .= " `Year` IN ('$val4')";  
} 

$stringgen1 = implode(' AND ', $QueryString1); //Aware that implode can be performed using Array
```

I tried adding `AND` at the end of the string itself like

```
$QueryString1 .= " `Re` IN ('$val2') AND"
```

this is working with the combination of inputs. But when I am passing only single input it is not working.

My complete SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE `it` IN ($val1) AND `Re` IN ('$val2')  AND $stringgen AND `Year` IN ('$val4')
```

Is there any other way other than implode 'AND' even with single input?

Comment: You have initialized `$QueryString` then you are using `$QueryString1`.

Comment: i thought of first build the input ($QueryString1) then implode the 'AND' after that i add it with $QueryString.to make complete query

Comment: Ok, but then I think you should edit your question by specifying all your code, and its actual output (not: it does not work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add you SQL WHERE clauses in an array before using implode.

```
$QueryString = "SELECT * FROM `table`"; 
$QueryWhere = array();

if ( (isset($val1) && !empty($val1)) ) { 
    $QueryWhere[] = "`it` IN ('$val1')"; 
} 

if ((isset($val2) && !empty($val2))) { 
    $QueryWhere[] = "`Re` IN ('$val2')"; 
} 

if ((isset($stringgen) && !empty($stringgen))) { 
    $QueryWhere[] = "$stringgen"; 
} 

if ((isset($val4) && !empty($val4))) { 
    $QueryWhere[] = "`Year` IN ('$val4')";  
} 

$QueryString .= (!empty($QueryWhere) ? ' WHERE ' : '') . implode(' AND ', $QueryWhere);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use isset and !empty together

```
<?php
$QueryString = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE";
if (!empty($val1))
{
    $QueryString1 .= " `it` IN ('$val1')";
}

if (!empty($val2))
{
    $QueryString1 .= " && `Re` IN ('$val2')";
}

if (!empty($stringgen))
{
    $QueryString1 .= " &&  $stringgen";
}

if (!empty($val4))
{
    $QueryString1 .= " &&  `Year` IN ('$val4')";
}
// Remove && from starting and ending of string
$stringgen1 = trim($QueryString1, "&&");
?>
```

Comment: thanks milan for your help. But this will not work if there is only one input we will get && between Where and inputs.

Comment: By using trim() function you can remove && from both side. I have already mention in answer.