# Imploding an array into a string to create a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I am creating a function that can be used to select an individual row from the database. The parameters of the function are select, table, and where (which is an array).

This is what I have so far:

```
  public function select_row($select, $table, $where = '') {
$sql = "SELECT {$select} FROM {$table}";

if(!empty($where)) {
  $sql .= " WHERE {$where} LIMIT 1";
} else {
  $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
}

echo $sql;}
```

What I am wanting to change is the $where variable, I am wanting to change it to an array, which will look like this:

```
$where = array('id' => '1');
```

But I am not too sure on how to do this, I tried implode() but I couldn't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Kieron

Comment: So you want $where to be an array that is imploded into an SQL WHERE clause? (aka as a string)

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: If that is something more than your training, like commercial or OS project, then it would be better if you would use one of popular DBAL libraries instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is asking for trouble. If you want this kind of functionality you should evaluate using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or
[Propel](http://propelorm.org/) which gives you all this and more.

Comment: Are you using the array to set a single value like 'id' => 1, or do you want to set multiple values like 'id' => 1, 'colX' => 2, 'colY' => 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can build out the where clause. But I suggest you use a query builder, for example here is cakePHP's http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html:

```
 <?php
 require 'connect.php';

 $firstname = 'Alex';
 $lastname = 'Smith';

 $query = 'SELECT * FROM users';

 $cond = array();
 $params = array();

 if (!empty($firstname)) {
     $cond[] = "firstname = ?";
     $params[] = $firstname;
 }

 if (!empty($lastname)) {
     $cond[] = "lastname = ?";
     $params[] = $lastname;
 }

 if (count($cond)) {
     $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $cond);
 }

 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute($params);

 foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
     print_r($row);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Can I do this with MySQLi instead of PDO?

Comment: The conditions above are building the query that can be used with mysqli. mysqli_query($con, $query);