# How to generate a WHERE clause from an array with multiple AND-conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML-table, where various selections can be made. The selected variables that contain the respective values, build the array `$data[]`. Now, with this array I would like to make an SQL request where all selected criteria should be met. This means, that I need the following request:

```
SELECT * FROM fruitgroups 
WHERE $selection[1] = $value[1] 
    AND $selection[2] = $value[2] 
    AND $selection[3] = $value[3] 
    etc ...
```

Can anybody please help me with the loop that generates exactly the string:

```
...
$selection[1] = $value[1] 
AND $selection[2] = $value[2] 
AND $selection[3] = $value[3] 
... etc ...
```

...that I need for the request?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [foreach](http://php.net/foreach), build an array, then [implode](http://php.net/implode)

Comment: check my answer @Columbus

Answer (score 0):

You can make a SQL request like this:

```
$selection = array("one", "two", "three");
$value = array("Tone", "Ttwo", "Tthree");
$concat = array();
foreach($selection as $key => $var){
    $new = $selection[$key] . " = " . $value[$key];
    array_push($concat, $new);
}
$concat = implode(" AND ", $concat);
$request = 'SELECT * FROM fruitgroups WHERE ' . $concat . ';';
echo $request;
```

[Run example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a4509679a678ec9d3eb89a381eaff3da7080531)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer above, but keep it simple and don't forget the single quotes around the values:

```
$clauses = [];
foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    $conditions[] = "{$selection[$i]} = '$value'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM fruitgroups WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
```

Even better, use an ORM like Eloquent:

```
$conditions = [];    
foreach ($values as $i => $value) {
    $conditions[$i] = $value;
}

$result = App\FruitGroups::where($conditions)->get();
```

I'm assuming you are sanitizing your inputs first, of course.